# XIB files still used in XCode and For IOS Development

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Can someone explain if there is still any use for nib or xib files in iOS development these days? Are xib files even still supported in XCode?

If you wanted to create a new app and/or multiple views in those apps in a non-programmatic way you would simply use Storyboard now. Am I thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use xibs all the time for common cells and views shared between different views. You can't do that with a storyboard.

Comment: I may be thinking about this incorrectly - what is a xib file exactly? I am not understanding it correctly from searching online

Comment: @user3216798 Let's say you have two tableView controllers. Both tableView controllers have a cell that looks exactly the same. If you use a storyboard, and you define both tableView controllers in that storyboard, you are going to have to draw / layout your cell two times. Once for each tableView. But if you draw / layout your cell in a xib file, then you can share that cell with both tableViews without having to draw it twice.

Comment: Ok got it - so xib files are still very much a part of the non-programmatic ios development process today? They are basically just used for building various components of a UI (ranging from small pieces to possibly a whole VC within Storyboard)?

Comment: @user3216798 Yes, it is very much still a part of the development process. Basically, you use interface builder to define your cells/views graphically. However, you don't necessarily need to import those cells/views into a storyboard, but you can. Once you create your xib, you can also load those views into existing views programatically.

Comment: Ok - so if you don't use Storyboard, where else could you create these xib files?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand your question. You use interface builder to define view controllers in a storyboard. You uses interface builder to construct a view in a xib. Now let's say you have a tableView controller. It makes no difference if you use a storyboard to create your tableView controller, or if you defined the whole thing programatically. The process would be the same. In your viewDidLoad method you would register the xib (or nib, I should say), by calling: tableView.register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String). The cell is then ready to use in the tableView

Comment: Ok I think I got it. Is Storyboard just a component of the Interface Builder? In other words the Interface Builder is a broader thing and is just what devs use to non-programmatically create UI elements for their app? And then, this means a xib file is simply any thing/file that is created for use in the Interface Builder

Comment: Correct. You can think of the interface builder as the tool. And a storyboard or a xib as the canvas.